Blazor Server EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these
I'm receiving this error: "EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these."
But I'm providing an (initialized) Model parameter to the EditForm like this:
Login.razor:

<div class="page"\>
<MudContainer Class="login-page-container" MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Medium"\>

        <div>
            <MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom Align="Align.Center" Class="font-bold">Welcome     Back!</MudText>
            <EditForm Model="@Input" method="post" OnSubmit="LoginUser" FormName="login">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <MudTextField Label="Email or Username" Placeholder="Email or Username"
                              @bind-Value="Input.EmailOrUsername" For="@(()=>                                                    Input.EmailOrUsername)"
                              Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" />
                <MudTextField Label="Password" Placeholder="Password"
                              @bind-Value="Input.Password" For="@(()=> Input.Password)"
                              InputType="InputType.Password" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" />
    
                <MudCheckBox Label="Remember Me"
                             @bind-Value="Input.RememberMe" For="@(()=> Input.RememberMe)" />
    
                <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" FullWidth="true">LOG IN</MudButton>
    
                <MudLink Typo="Typo.overline" href="#" Class="sign-up">DON'T HAVE AN ACCOUNT? SIGN UP</MudLink>
            </EditForm>
        </div>
    
        <MudLink Href="#" Underline="Underline.Always" Class="text-center font-bold">RESET PASSWORD</MudLink>
    </MudContainer>

Login.razor.cs:

public sealed partial class Login
{
[CascadingParameter]
private HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }
[SupplyParameterFromQuery]
private string? ReturnUrl { get; set; }
[SupplyParameterFromForm]
private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (HttpContext != null && HttpMethods.IsGet(HttpContext.Request.Method))
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
        }
    }
    
    public async Task LoginUser()
    {
        ...
    }
    
    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        public string EmailOrUsername { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

}

I've tried interactive mode, but it doesn't work with HttpContext.
I want to mantain the autocomplete from the browser as well. But nothing seems to work properly.
Thanks!

Jesus, I stopped using MudTextField  and now it's working (using plain InputText)...

That should make no difference.  Though you haven't provided the full error message, that normally comes from EditForm.
